# How to reset countdown timer in spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, nstimeinterval

How to reset countdown timer when the score is divisible by 10?

Here is the score method

```
-(void)setScore:(int)score
{
    _score = score;
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", score];
}
```

the update method that counts down time

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    if (startGamePlay) {
        startTime = currentTime;
        startGamePlay = NO;
    }

    int countDownInt = 10.0 - (int)(currentTime - startTime);
    timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countDownInt];

    if (self.score % 10 == 0) {

        //reset countDownInt here

    }

}
```

Comment: what's the problem with this code?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: I failed to find a line of code to make the countDownInt start(restart) counting from 10 secs when the score is divisible by 10.

Comment: make countDownInt an ivar